# best practices on joining data during ETL

Tags: bigdata, etl

I've been googling around and can't really find a answer to my question. Lets say i have 2 large tables and my final destination table requires rows that are joined between these 2 tables. In terms of scalability and best practices, where should I do these joins? On the source database? In memory after extraction? Or staging tables?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't really a set rule for. It depends on where do you need the joined data and what your warehouse practises are. I for instance, like to keep all tables in staging exactly the same structure as the source. If I wouldn't need the joined data at the source I would join the data in the datamart where it will be used.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, there are no rules here, just common sense.
It is good to get rid of the unnecessary data as soon as possible, so you will spend less resources/storage down the road, but you should consider impact on your PROD environment.

> staging tables

Having copy of the data in Staging gives you more freedom and flexibility, ability to try different ETL approaches, and etc. I would do it there. 
Even if you ETL looks simple for now, it can grow in the future, so you need a quite place to play with your data.

> in memory

in memory where? If it is a prod instance, and you consume 95% of memory... :) All computations are "in memory" anyway.

Best regards.